# ArrayList add private access error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to create an array list which is created using variables inputting by the user.
It is created in a switch statement and I'm getting this error about the add statement when adding data to the array list.

```java
add(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], int) has private access in java.util.ArrayList
```

Code below:

```
String stringE30 = Integer.toString(ratingE30);
String stringE36 = Integer.toString(ratingE36);
String stringE46 = Integer.toString(ratingE46);
String stringE92 = Integer.toString(ratingE92);
String stringF80 = Integer.toString(ratingF80);

ArrayList<String> arrayListToFile = new ArrayList<>();
arrayListToFile.add("E30", "1985", stringE30);
arrayListToFile.add("E36", "1992", stringE36);
arrayListToFile.add("E46", "2000", stringE46);
arrayListToFile.add("E92", "2007", stringE92);
arrayListToFile.add("F80", "2014", stringF80);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The method you are trying to use isn't public, you must either use  `add(int index, String s)` or `add(String s)`

Comment: Could you explain what you think `arrayListToFile.add("E30", "1985", stringE30);` does?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `add` with 3 parameters.

The IDE assume that you want to call the `add` version with 3 parameters but it's privated so it raises error.

You have to wrap your data in a class and add it to your list:

```
public class Data {
   private String name;
   private String year;
   private String rating;

   public Data(String name, String year, String rating) {
    this.name = name; 
    this.year = year;
    this.rating = rating;
   }
}
```

Then you add to your list by:

```
List<Data> arrayListToFile = new ArrayList<>();

arrayListToFile.add(new Data("E30", "1985", stringE30));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. This seems to have worked apart from i know get this error on the arraylist add line of code:         com.company.Main.this cannot be referenced from a static context